# Error when reallocating dynamic unsigned char array with invalid next size error

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

I'm attempting to create a dynamic unsigned char array that grows in number of rows per each element added:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE 1

int main()
{
    unsigned char **p = NULL, rows = 0;
    // initialize p pointer to as the size of one char
    p = malloc ( BLOCKSIZE * sizeof ( unsigned char *) );
    // add 10 "TEST" elements
    for (;rows < 10; rows++ )
    {
        if (rows > BLOCKSIZE) {
            // allocate memory for each row
            p = realloc (p, rows * sizeof ( unsigned char *) );
        }
        // allocate memory for each column
        p[rows] = malloc (rows * sizeof (unsigned char  ));
        // add element
        p[rows] = "TEST";
    }
    for (int i=0; i < rows; i++)
        printf("%s\n", p[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

The code outputs this error when run:

```
realloc(): invalid next size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Could someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `p[rows]` is invalid as your array only has `rows` elements, numbered from `0` to `rows-1`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. could you please elaborate more?

Comment: I'm not sure what else could be said about it. You have *three* boxes. Count them: one is labelled "Box 0", one is labelled "Box 1", one is labelled "Box 2". What happens when you try to open Box 3? There is no Box 3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- In the `realloc` call:

```
p = realloc (p, rows * sizeof ( unsigned char *) );
```

In the first iteration of the cycle `rows` is 0, allocating 0 bytes makes it impossible for the first row to hold the assignment, and in subsequent reallocations there is not enough space for the number of pointers you are assigning, there is always one less than needed, this results in invalid access to unallocated memory.

You should at least reallocate with the size of 1 `unsigned char*`, you can also use the pointer itself (`sizeof *p`) in the block size:

```
p = realloc (p, (rows + BLOCKSIZE) * sizeof *p);
```

- The second `malloc` does not reserve enough space, it should have at least the size of string you assign to it, plus the space for the null-terminator so 4 + 1.

```
p[rows] = malloc (5 * sizeof **p);
```

- `rows` should be at the very least of `int` type, and ideally `size_t`, it's used to index the array there is no reason for it to be `unsigned char`.
- As it is, the assignment of "TEST" is causing a memory leak, you are simply making `p[rows]` point to a string literal rather than to the memory block previously allocated. You should use:

```
memcpy(p[rows], "TEST", 5);
```

Or `strcpy` for signed `char`.

Fixed code([Online](https://godbolt.org/z/yRuSqV)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE 1

int main()
{
    unsigned char **p = NULL;
    size_t rows = 0;
    p = malloc ( BLOCKSIZE * sizeof *p);
    if(p == NULL){        //always check for allocation failure
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    for (;rows < 10; rows++ )
    {
        if (rows > BLOCKSIZE) {
            p = realloc (p, (rows + BLOCKSIZE) * sizeof *p );
        }
        if(p == NULL){
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        //in this case the row is always 4 + 1 chars, but you can have different number of chars per row
        p[rows] = malloc (5 * sizeof **p);
        if(p[rows] == NULL){
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }    
        memcpy(p[rows], "TEST", 5);
    }
    for (size_t i=0; i < rows; i++)
        printf("%s\n", p[i]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I realize my answer was incomplete, but downvoting with no comments seems harsh, and of no benefit, anyway, the answer is now comprehensive in analysis and correction of all the issues.

Comment: Not my DV, but 0 is not an invalid size for `malloc` / `realloc`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I wasn't aware that 0 was a valid size, so what's causing the error?

Comment: The problem does appear to be with the reallocation.  When it reallocates, the program provides room for `nrows` elements, which is not enough for subsequently accessing the element at index `nrows`.  The diagnostic likely reflects one of the resulting invalid accesses having corrupted the memory allocation metadata.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I believe that's the case, anyway though I didn't know, it wasn't my intention to state that 0 was invalid per se, but to say that 0 wasn't valid because it can't hold the assignment. I guess I'll clarify that.

Answer (score -1):

you have some bugs and i will try to explaing them and fix the code:

```
unsigned char **p = NULL, rows = 0;
```

rows is `unsigned char` type. why? it needs to of type `size_t` (becuase later we will use it in the maloc/realoc, and better to be of size_t.

```
for (;rows < 10; rows++ ){
...
```

so , i asume that you have typo and you have tried to iterate over integer/size_t data type not
`unsigned char`!

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

> The `realloc()` function shall deallocate the old object pointed to by
> ptr and return a pointer to a new object that has the size specified
> by size.  The contents of the new object shall be the same as that of
> the old object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of the new and
> old sizes. Any bytes in the new object beyond the size of the old
> object have indeterminate values.
> Upon successful completion, realloc() shall return a pointer to the
> (possibly moved) allocated space. If size is 0, either: A null pointer shall be returned and errno set to an implementation-defined value.

Any way assume that `rows` is of type size_t (inside the for loop), you need to reallocate like this:
so, how to use realloc ?

```
unsigned char **p_temp = p;
p_temp = (unsigned char**)realloc(p_temp, (rows + BLOCKSIZE)*sizeof(unsigned char*));
if(p_temp ==NULL){
/*realloc failed but we still have p ! we didnt encounter a memory leak like your code*/
....
}
else{
p = p_temp; /*let p to point to the new allocated buffer */
}
```

```
p[rows] = malloc (rows * sizeof (unsigned char  ));
```

the same problems here!

Any way i didnt understand the logic in your code ? why not to allocate enough space and omit the call to `realloc()`?

Comment: It is ok for `nrows` to have type `unsigned char` as long as that type's range is sufficient for the actual number of rows the program is to handle.  I see nothing in the OP's program that inherently conflicts with that choice of type.

Comment: In any event, although you do make good points about checking the results of memory allocation functions, nothing in this answer seems to address the OP's actual question.